# item inside component access

Tags: qml

I have the following qml file:

```
import QtQuick 1.0
Component{

    Column{
        id: interHeader;

        Item{
         id:interItem
         height: 300
         width: 200

             Text{
                 id:title
                 text:"Text"
                 anchors.centerIn: parent
                 font.bold: true
                 elide:"ElideRight"
                 color: "Black"
             }
         }

        Item {
            width: parent.width
            height: 100

            //onClick event
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent

                onClicked:{
                        console.log("Ok");
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

The problem is that I need to assign some KeyNavigation to the interItem.
I want to access the interItem from another qml file.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

There really is no benefit of using `Component` in a completely separate QML file. Remove Component and name your Qml file with a capital letter - e.g. InterHeader

Then define a `property` under your root item. For example:

```
import QtQuick 1.0
Item {
id: interHeader
property variant keyActionUp
Keys.onUpPressed: keyActionUp
}
```

OR

You can use the `Connections` function to execute callbacks for signals from interHeader.

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-connections.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The fact that I use the Component because it's the header or footer of a listView, I already named my qml file with a capital letter.

Using the property variant I can link to a property not an item such as 'title', also the connections functions are not useful in this case.

Comment: OK that makes sense. Why don't you define your interHeader component inside an item. Alias properties in that item to your component

Comment: The header should be a component not an item so if I put it inside an Item I should find a method to access it , so I came back to the same problem